# CNTK basic operation with c# following python example gives error

Tags: c#, function, evaluation, cntk

at this moment I'm struggling to not desperate just trying to convert this (from https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/gettingstarted.html#overview-and-first-run)

```
cntk.minus([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]).eval()
```

which gives "*array([-3., -3., -3.], dtype=float32)*"

to

```
    public static void Test1()
    {
        var device = DeviceDescriptor.GPUDevice(0);

        var v1 = CNTKLib.InputVariable(new int[] { 1 }, DataType.Float, "e1");
        var v2 = CNTKLib.InputVariable(new int[] { 1 }, DataType.Float, "e2");

        var o1 = CNTKLib.InputVariable(new int[] { 1 }, DataType.Float, "o1");
        var o2 = CNTKLib.InputVariable(new int[] { 1 }, DataType.Float, "o2");


        var features1 = new float[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        var features2 = new float[] { 4, 5, 6 };

        var vv1 = Value.CreateBatch<float>(new int[] { 1 }, features1, device);
        var vv2 = Value.CreateBatch<float>(new int[] { 1 }, features2, device);


        var d1 = new Dictionary<Variable, Value>()
        {
            { v1, vv1 },
            { v2, vv2 },
        };

        var d2 = new Dictionary<Variable, Value>();

        d2.Add(o1, null);

        var fun = CNTK.CNTKLib.Minus(v1, v2);
        fun.Evaluate(d1, d2, device);
    }
```

which gives the next error:

"*Values for 1 required arguments 'Input('o1', [1], [*, #])', that the requested output(s) 'Input('o1', [1], [*, #])' depend on, have not been provided*"

I cannot understand how the documentation for the c# is so empty and how can be so easy in python.

The same can be applied to the next example

```
import numpy as np
x = cntk.input_variable(2)
y = cntk.input_variable(2)
x0 = np.asarray([[2., 1.]], dtype=np.float32)
y0 = np.asarray([[4., 6.]], dtype=np.float32)
cntk.squared_error(x, y).eval({x:x0, y:y0})
->array([ 29.], dtype=float32)
```

numpy arrays just parse perfectly as dictionaries. I was trying to do the same in C# (hardly following the examples in https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Examples/TrainingCSharp/Common/LogisticRegression.cs) but the same error.

is anybody able to help me to figure out what I'm missing? also maybe to point to some documentation with basic examples for the usage of the api in c#.

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

you might want to take a look at [this github repo](https://github.com/anastasios-stamoulis/deep-learning-with-csharp-and-cntk). It probably has everything you need.

Comment: Hi snowflake, thanks a lot for the answer. I'll have a look at it : )